# Python method positional args troubleshooting

Tags: python, function, methods, arguments

So I am trying to make a script that will traverse a string and replace certain characters.  The idea is fairly simple and sudo code looks a little like this.

```
Input1 = ''
Input2 = ''
Input3 = ''
rawPw = Input1 + Input2 + Input 3
Remove spaces if any exist
Creates a new empty str called finalPw

Scan the rawPw string one character at a time.  Each character goes to a Random bool and if True it goes to get converted.  If false it appends finalPw

In it goes to conversion it checks against a list of specified characters and if it matches it goes to a specific converter method.  Otherwise it will just swap upper/lower case and append finalPw

The specific converter method will use a predefined list of characters that it can be replaced by, and will use random.choice() to pick from that list to replace the character and append finalPw.
```

This is the code I have so far, note the upper/lower case swapping is not part of it yet, I am building and testing the code piecemeal because my last prototype was 350 lines long and a complete failure.  So going from scratch here.

```
import random


print("Enter 3 words or series of numbers or both, each entry must be at least 5 characters in length")


def main():
    input1 = 'Jim'
    input2 = 'Samantha'
    input3 = 'Ethan'
    rawPw = (input1 + input2 + input3)
    refinedPw = rawPw.replace(' ', '')
    print(refinedPw)
    finalPw = ''
    convertTrain(refinedPw)


def switch():
    switchVal = random.choice(True, False)
    return switchVal


def convertTrain():
    temp = main.refinedPw
    onOff = False
    for i in temp:
        switch(i)
        if i == True:
            if i == 'i':
                the_iExc(i)
        else:
            main.finalPw.append(i)


def the_iExc():
    rep_iExc = ['i', '!']
    repVal = random.choice(rep_iExc)
    for i in len(main.refinedwPw):
        slice(i)
        if i == 'i':
            i.replace(repVal)
            return i

main()
```

The error I am receiving is :
line 15, in main
convertTrain(refinedPw)
TypeError: convertTrain() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I have tried changing things around a bit to see if I can't fix the positional argument, so much so that I have stripped it of all classes and am just going classless until I get it to work.  For the life of me I can't seem to get it to use the appropriate number of args.

Comment: `refinedPw` is not an attribute of the function `main`; it's a local variable that you are attempting to pass to a function that hasn't defined any parameters. I'm not sure what language's idioms or procedures you are projecting on to Python, but I suggest working with the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) a bit.

Comment: There's also no need to use `rawPw.replace` here, since by definition you already know that it contains no spaces. Each of the three `input*` variables is space-free, and `+` will not introduce any spaces.

Comment: chepner, the three variables are placeholders for testing, they will be user inputs in the final version

Answer (score 0):

This line defines convertTrain as a function that takes no arguments:

```
def convertTrain():
```

But then inside main() you call it with an argument:

```
convertTrain(refinedPw)
```

Either change the function definition to accept an argument, or change the call to not pass an argument.

Comment: It should be passing refinedPw through the function so that refinedPw can be changed by convertTrain().  So do I just put refinedPw into both?  Or do I need to do something else, because calling and casting seems to screw me up time and time again.  Obvioulsy still learning to code.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to invoke function with arguments here:

```py
convertTrain(refinedPw)
```

...but there are no arguments in the function's definition

```py
def convertTrain()
```

To fix this, add a new argument for the `convertTrain` function, like this:

```py
def convertTrain(train) # Name of argument can be changed if needed
```

Read more about function declaration here: [click this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)